# How to place images on a canvas in a grid pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, algorithm, html5-canvas

I'm looking to add different sized images in a tiled pattern to a set width and height HTML canvas.

Something like this:
[image]

This can be done with a div and CSS grid. Something like:

```
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.wide {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.tall {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

But to do this with the canvas element I need to work out their positions and dimensions.

Is there an npm package, algorithm, or technique that I could use to calculate the positions and dimensions of the images to be placed on to the canvas?

I am using React.

Comment: By "canvas" I'm assuming you don't mean the <canvas /> element? Since that's controlled by javascript, not css.

Comment: In the example you seem to have 4 formats: 1x1 block, 1x2 block, 2x1 block, 2x2 block. Is that the case always, or are the images just any random size?

Comment: Random sized images